PyGame фон остаётся чёрным без спрайта
Проблема есть в PyGame. У меня записано, чтобы фон был белым , а в итоге итак итак он чёрный без спрайта.
Вот код:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pygame, os, sys

# Переменные
worldx = 960
worldy= 720
fps = 40 #частота кадров
ani = 4 #циклы анимации
main = True


# Объекты
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #персонаж сам
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) # type: ignore (тут тоже надо 2 подчеркивания
        self.images = []

        img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', 'hero1.png'))
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


# Настройка
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game / Newtonioapple")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx, worldy])
player = Player() #создать спрайт
player.rect.x = 0 #x
player.rect.y = 0 #y
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)

# Главный цикл
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            try:
                sys.exit()
            finally:
                main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord("q"):
                pygame.quit()
            try:
                sys.exit()
            finally:
                main = False

world.fill(255, 255, 255) # type: ignore
player_list.draw(world)
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(fps)

Как решить беду?

часть кода обновляющая экран и отрисовывающая спрайты, находится вне цикла из-за этого у вас и проблема, сами разберетесь или вам написать решение?
